# CloudEndpointsのResourceContainerについて

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/create_api

に従ってCloudEndpointsでAPIの作成を試みております。

サンプルで提示されている
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples
python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo
を使用して色々試しておりますが、パラメータの定義でわからない点があります。

パスパラメータのみでボディパラメータが不要なAPI、echo_path_parameterを定義すべく以下の様に書いたのですが

```
# [START messages]
class EchoRequest(messages.Message):
    fuga = messages.StringField(1)
    hoge = messages.StringField(2)

#sampleそのまま
ECHO_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    EchoRequest,
    n=messages.IntegerField(3, default=1))

#echo_path_parameter用
TEST_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    message_types.VoidMessage,
    test=messages.IntegerField(2, default=1))
# [END messages]

...

    #sampleそのまま
    @endpoints.method(
        # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
        ECHO_RESOURCE,
        # This method returns an Echo message.
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo',
        http_method='POST',
        name='echo')
    def echo(self, request):
        output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
        return EchoResponse(content=output_content)

    #パスパラメータのみボディパラメータなし
    @endpoints.method(
        # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
        TEST_RESOURCE,
        # This method returns an Echo message.
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo/{test}',
        http_method='POST',
        name='echo_path_parameter')
    def echo_path_parameter(self, request):
        output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.test)
        return EchoResponse(content=output_content)
```

これを
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_openapi_spec main.EchoApi --hostname xxxxx
コマンドにかけると

```
"definitions": {
 "MainEchoResponse": {
   "properties": {
     "content": {
       "type": "string"
     }
   },
   "type": "object"
 },
 "ProtorpcMessagesCombinedContainer": {　★ECHO_RESOURCEの定義
   "properties": {
     "fuga": {
       "type": "string"
     },
     "hoge": {
       "type": "string"
     },
     "n": {
       "format": "int64",
       "type": "string"
     }
   },
   "type": "object"
 }
},
...
 "/echo/v1/echo/{test}": {
   "post": {
     "operationId": "EchoApi_echoPathParameter",
     "parameters": [
       {
         "format": "int64",
         "in": "path",
         "name": "test",
         "required": true,
         "type": "string"
       },
       {
         "in": "body",
         "name": "body",
         "schema": {
           "$ref": "#/definitions/ProtorpcMessagesCombinedContainer" ★ECHO_RESOURCEが参照されてしまう
         }
       }
     ],
```

というように、echo_path_parameter()で定義しているTEST_RESOURCEは無視されECHO_RESOURCE側が$refに入ってしまいます。

sample実装で先に書いてあるecho()内のアノテーションECHO_RESOURCEを外すと、TEST_RESOURCEが読まれるようになります。
また関数定義の順番を逆にするとecho()側がTEST_RESOURCEが$refに設定されます。

この動作は仕様動作となりますでしょうか？
一つのAPIにResourceContainerは一つしか定義できないのでしょうか？